# C++ set a pointer of pointer to null?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on some kind of smart pointer technique but there is one piece I'm missing. I tried several combinations but the logic is as follow:

```
UInt *obj = new UInt;
UInt *ref;
ref = obj;

delete obj;
obj = NULL;

if (ref == NULL)
{
    // It works
}
else
{
    // It failed
}
```

Is there any way to hit "It Works" without setting ref to NULL explicitly?

EDIT:

A more appropriate scenario would be something like this:

```
class A
{
public:

    A(): ref(NULL) {}
    ~A()
    {
        if (ref != NULL)
            delete ref;
    }
    int *ref;
};

    int *obj = new int;
    A *host = new A();

    host->ref = obj; ???

    delete obj;
      obj = NULL;

    if (host->ref == NULL)
    {
        // It works.
    }
    else
    {
        // It failed.
    }
```

...

Can't use int*& ref as a class member though.... must be close.

Comment: Is `UInt` your smart pointer class? Smart pointers should not be allocated on the heap.

Comment: What does "pointer of pointer" stand for in the title of the question?

Comment: There are no smart pointers in this code.

Comment: I'm sorry, forget about the smart pointer scenario. UInt could be int instead.

Comment: yeah i am going to have to concur with the other comments.  those pointers seem pretty dumb to me.

Comment: You are right, I did not try to illustrate a smart pointer technique but the missing piece I need to make it work. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, you should be using a smart pointer:

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<UInt> obj = std::make_shared<UInt>();
std::weak_ptr<UInt> ref = obj;

obj.reset();

if (ref.expired())
{
    // It works
}
else
{
    // It failed
}
```

Don't try managing your own memory when the standard library has facilities to do it for you.

Comment: Exactly, so that people who read your code will not need to read and understand your own implementation, when there is a standard that everybody knows.
Also, most probably, standard will have it better than yours.

Comment: True, I never use the std lib, I guess I could give it a try. I'm still interested how I could accomplish the example.

Answer (score 3):

Declare ref as a reference to pointer

```
Uint*& ref = obj;
```

ref will now refer to the obj pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Intially both `obj` and `ref` point to the (same) `UInt` instance. Then you delete the instance and set `obj` to `NULL`. But `ref` is just like any other regular pointer, so it still points to the deleted instance.

Instead you can create a reference variable, or in this case a 'reference pointer' by adding `&` to the declaration:

```
Uint*& ref = obj;
```

Then `ref` really refers to `obj` and keeps the same value (pointer) as `obj`.

Comment: Oh excellent, I used this example for simplicity sake but what if ref is a class member?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data provides some details, cons and pros of references as class members vs pointers