# Assign a reference to a fstream object to an existing fstream object

Tags: c++, fstream

I am working on a spell checker program .

```
public:
SpellChecker(fstream& fileName)
    :dic("wordEn.txt"),
    fileToSpell(fileName),
    appendbleChanges()
{
}

private:
    Dictionary dic;//dictionary
    fstream& fileToSpell;
    stringMap appendbleChanges;//map that save changes to the words in the file
```

this is a simplified version of the class . creating dictionary is expensive , and i did not want the client to create it , so i made spell checker responsible to make it. then it was logical , to provide a setFile() function that enables spell checker class to work on new files, without creating a dictionary again .

```
void SpellChecker::setFile(fstream& fileName)
{
    appendbleChanges.clear();//clear the previous history 

    fileToSpell.open(fileName);//wrong!!
}
```

But i can't find a way to assign fileName to fileToSpell . assignment operator is deleted , and i am aware of using std::move() but it is not what i want to do , what if client wants to make further changes to the file after spellchecking ?? i can provide a getFile() function , but it is not nice to make client remember that ...

Comment: You can use pointers. You cannot change what a reference refers to after it was initialised.

Comment: @Midas this means i will have same file open in two places if i have fstream object in my class ?!

Comment: I think I edited my comment after you replied. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data

Comment: @Midas I always miss that point .thanks , dummy question 

Comment: @oldrinb I think you can post that as an answer.

Comment: @oldrinb that's the answer