# Class design when one class contains an instance of another class

Tags: c++

I give the following example to illustrate my question. Suppose `Abc` is a class that will use another class (`Def`). Assume `Def` is a large class with many class members (expensive for copying), it make more sense to let the pointer to a Def object be part of Abc class. Then when implementing `Abc` class function `do1`, it can refers to Def object via its pointer `pDef`.

```
class Abc
{
  public:
        Abc(Def &def)
        {
           pDef = &def;
        }
        ~Abc()
        {
         }
        void do1();
   private:
        Def *pDef;

}
```

However, if I implement class Abc in this way, I will have the risk that the `Def` pointer might be invalid. Any ideas on improving this class design?  One idea I have is to use share pointer:

```
 class Abc
    {
      public:
            Abc(boost::shared_ptr<Def> def)
            {
               pDef = def;
            }
            ~Abc()
            {
             }
            void do1();
       private:
            boost::shared_ptr<Def> pDef;

    }
```

EDIT: I want to make it clear that my main purpose is to avoid the expensive copy operation when constructing class `Abc`. For me using the shared pointer and James Adkison's solution (accepted answer) can both solve the problem. But the effect on the expensive `Def` object may be different. Using shared pointer will keep many copies of the object while using James Adkison's solution will only keep one copy of `Def` object.

Comment: Does `pDef` *really* have to be a pointer? And don't look at the smart pointers as simply self-deleting pointers and a way of faking garbage collection, look at them from an *ownership* perspective: Do your `Abc` instances share *ownership* of the `Def` instance or not? Also note that maybe you should be using `weak_ptr` instead?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data?

Comment: Why can't `Abc` own `pDef` and use move and copy semantics as appropriate?

Comment: If you have access to C++11, I would look into accepting a unique_ptr in the ctor so that you know you will own the memory. If you're not allowed to be the sole owner, use a `shared_ptr`. With raw pointers it's all about contracts (preconditions and postconditions) for managing lifetime, which is usually really difficult to puzzle out and notoriously ambiguous.

Comment: "Assume Def is a large class with many class members" -- Does this mean _data members_? If you're implying the class is expensive to copy just explicitly state it.

Comment: @James Adkison  using move seems to be a good solution, can you put your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assume Def is a large class with many class members

I assume this means that it is expensive to copy the `Def` class. However, with C++11 you could implement move semantics for `Def` and keep the `Abc` implementation simple and efficient.

**Note:** This answer is based on the assumption that the only reason the question uses any pointers (smart or otherwise) is as a way to avoid expensive copies.

#### Example Code

```
class Def
{
public:
    Def() {}
    Def(const Def& other) { /* ... */ } // Copy constructor even though it's expensive
    Def(Def&& other) { /* ... */ } // Move constructor for efficiency

    Def& operator=(const Def& other) { /* ... */ } // Copy assignment
    Def& operator=(Def&& other) { /* ... */ } // Move assignment
};
```

Now the `Def` class supports copy semantics, even though copy the class may be expensive. However, it also supports move semantics to allow efficient usage when a copy isn't required.

```
class Abc
{
public:
    Abc() {}

    Abc(const Def& def) : mDef(def) {} // Perform an expensive copy

    Abc(Def&& def) : mDef(std::move(def)) {} // Perform a move

    // Implement any other member functions which could accept Def
    // via copy or move

private:
    Def mDef;
};
```

---

I would only advocate using `std::shared_ptr` if the use case is actually to support shared ownership semantics.

Comment: I'd like to hear back from the OP why this answer was accepted. It seems that the real issue was not shared ownership, but rather having to construct a temporary `Def` object only to pass it to an `Abc` constructor. Because with this approach, there is a `1-to-1` relationship between `Abc` and `Def`, while in the shared pointer approach, there is a `1-to-many` relationship from `Def` to `Abc`. It wasn't entirely clear from the question what relationship the OP desired.

Comment: @rwols I agree with you that is unclear. This is why I stated my assumption about the OP only using pointers as a mechanism to avoid expensive copy operations (of course that assumption could have been wrong).

Comment: @rwols @ James Adkison Thanks for the discussion. My main problem is to avoid expensive copy operations. I will reorganize my questions to make it clear.

Comment: @feelfree from the editted question I agree that James' answer is the solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why use a pointer if you can use a reference?

```
class Abc
{
public:
    Abc(Def &def) : pDef(def)
    {
    }

    void do1();
private:
    Def& pDef;
}
```

You aren't passing ownership, so there's no need for pointers.

Think of a reference like a pointer that can never be null.

Comment: Having an reference data member prevents an auto generated copy assignment operator whereas a pointer doesn't.

Comment: Well, just write one. It beats leaking any day.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't guarantee a leak and neither protect against the `Abc` instance outliving the `def` instance passed in the constructor.

Comment: To guarantee that, he'd need to put def inside Abc.

Comment: Using a reference doesn't buy you anything, and it makes assignment non-intuitive.

Comment: If you aren't using pointers then you can let RAII take care of object lifetime. Assignment is still fine if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Using pointers or references here has absolutely nothing to do with RAII.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `std::shared_ptr` is for. If you use `std::shared_ptr`, the pointer will always be valid (as long as you follow all the very simple rules).