# Can I intialuze a reference of the same class type in a constructor rather then cpy-ctor?

Tags: c++, reference

If I have a class called `Bar` which has an element of `Bar&` which is a reference to the same class type then I have a constructor that takes an object of the same class by reference to initialize that member then is that constructor a copy constructor or a simple constructor? :

```
struct Bar;
struct Bar 
{
    //Bar(Bar); // error: a cpy-ctor must take a reference
    //Bar(const Bar& = Bar()); // error
    Bar(Bar&); // is this a copy-ctor?
    Bar& b1;
};
```

So as you can see above I need a version of a constructor to initialize the reference member but the copy-ctor is called. So is there some way to initialize it without a cpy-ctor?

Comment: How would you ever construct such an object?  If a class needs to hold a reference to another object of it's same type, user pointers (smart or otherwise).

Comment: Note that using reference members is discouraged. In most cases they are too constraining and pointer members are just better. See [Should I prefer pointers or references in member data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data).

Comment: *"is this a copy-ctor?"* Yes, that it is.

Comment: `Bar(const Bar& = Bar());` is both a copy constructor and a default constructor, and using if for default initialisation would never stop creating `Bar`s.

Answer (score 1):

You might do:

```
struct Bar 
{
    Bar() : b1(*this){}
    Bar(Bar& rhs) : b1(rhs) {}
    Bar& b1;
};
```

> Bar(Bar&); // is this a copy-ctor?

Yes,

non-template constructors taking (possibly cv qualifier) reference, following by optional default parameters are copy constructor.