# How to initialize member variables before inherited classes

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make one class which requires member variables to be initialized first. I know why this happens, but is there a way around this?

Current print order:
second
first

Wanted print order:
first
second

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "first" << '\n';
    }
};

struct B {
    B() {
        std::cout << "second" << '\n';
    }
};

struct C : public B {

    C() : a(), B() {

    }

    A a;

};

int main() {

    C c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: short answer is no. Maybe if you explain why you need it we can tell you what to do instead.

Comment: Look at [base_from_member idiom](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/base_from_member.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick your members that need initializing first in a struct and inherit privately from that, before `B`.

```
struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "first" << '\n'; }
};

struct B {
    B() { std::cout << "second" << '\n'; }
};

struct Members { A a; };

struct C : private Members, public B {
    C() : Members(), B() {}
};

int main() {
    C c;
}
```

The downside with this is that there is no way to avoid exposing the "member struct" to the outside world, but that shouldn't be a problem in practice.

Comment: Thanks! I see this as the best solution for my case so far.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ base classes will be initialized before any member variables of a derived class.

The best recourse given the information you've provided is to prefer composition over inheritance:

```
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "first" << '\n';
    }
};

struct B {
    B() {
        std::cout << "second" << '\n';
    }
};

struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

This will exhibit the [desired behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/jqaT51o4e)

Answer (score -2):

Make `A` a needed reference for `C`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "first" << '\n';
    }
};

struct B {
    B() {
        std::cout << "second" << '\n';
    }
};

struct C : public B {
    C(const A& a) : _A(a), B() {}
    const A& _A;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    C c(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `C(A a = {}) : B{}, _A{std::move(a)} {}`?  It's usually better to pass by value when storing a copy.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX That does not answer the question because explicit creating an object of the type A A a; has nothing common with the described problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight can you explain me the difference going on here? As I see, you pass a copy which then is moved?

Comment: There's only moves (not a copy) if an rvalue is passed.  That's the difference.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow problem:  "...requires member variables to be initialized first" solution: "initialized the member first". I see no problem here. If you want you can write a factory which does that for you...

Comment: @TobySpeight but I don't want to copy it?

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_A`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't define them in your code.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX You are mistaken. It is not the member variable that is initialized first. It is the base class that is initialized first. The displayed message is related to the declaration A a;.

Comment: Exactly.  That's why you want `std::move()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight there is no copy being made, the member is a reference

Comment: @PeteBecker I did it for simplification but yes you are right!

Comment: Oh yes, it's a reference.  Oops.  It was a value member in the original (so no lifetime issues to worry about).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the class itself needs that the "member" is initialized before hand. That is requirement fullfilled by design

Comment: Technically the member (`_A`) is still initialized after `B`, though an `A` is constructed before `B`. Whether or not this applies to this question depends on why they want this order of initialization.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Do you understand what I have written? It is the sub-object of the base class that is initialized first in your program. The message relative to the class A that you see  is issued by the declaration A a;.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes the real problem here is, that the question is not clear enough to give a good solution.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes I understand that. It depends on the use-case WHY the user wants it in that order, then we can provide maybe a different or better solution. My solution requires A to be initialized before B and C which totally fullfills the given requirements

Comment: There's a different between an object being _constructed_ and a member being _initialised_.  This answer might be what's wanted, but you should be clear about why you've presented something different than requested.  I wouldn't say that this "totally fullfills the given requirements" - it meets something similar to the requirements, and you should state what's different.  It will matter if `B` is constructed with arguments that cause `this->A` to be accessed, for example.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX We are specking about initialization of DATA  MEMBER a before initialization of the base class. You answer has nothing common with such a situation.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes you are right, but I think we should OP not overhelm with bad coding style solutions like private inheritance and using a better solution like dependency injection

Comment: @VladfromMoscow downvote it if that makes you happy. Maybe teach people writing cleaner code and better solutions instead of sticking to pitfalls like multi-inheritance and private inheritance

Comment: @RoQuOTriX `private` inheritance is not inherently bad or unclean code. There are actually fewer risks involved in `private` inheritance than there are with `public` inheritance and it is a fully encapsulated design decision (it has no effect at all on the type's user). Where as the solution presented in this answer introduces a lifetime concern where the user has to be sure the `B` doesn't outlive the `A`. Furthermore, reference type data members introduce [very significant restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/892303/7359094) and should be avoided.