# Pass by reference vs pointer

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I am having a hard time wrapping around knowing when to use pointers vs references. My question is: in Java/C# you can pass an object as an argument to a function and then assign this argument to an internal class variable so that you can use it outside the scope of the method later on. However, in C++ I am not sure how to achieve the same thing. If I pass by reference, I can only use it within the scope of that method. If I assign the reference to an internal variable of the same type, changes on one don't affect the other. I cannot declare an uninitialized reference either (maybe through constructor). The only solutions I have found are to either pass in the reference every time I need to work with it (as an argument) or pass in a pointer instead once (e.g. through a constructor) and convert it to a reference every time I need to use it outside the scope.

Here is an example method I have for testing this:

1. initially the value referenced by get and setValue is set to zero.
2. I call Controller2.initialize(Controller &controller, Controller *controllerPtr)
3. I call Controller2::process(Controller &controller)

The output is shown after the code blocks below

```
#include "Controller2.h"

Controller2::Controller2()
{
}

void Controller2::initialize(Controller &controller, Controller *controllerPtr)
{
    _controller = controller;
    _controllerPtr = controllerPtr;

    Controller &controllerRef = *_controllerPtr;

    controller.setValue(5);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("_Controller in initialize(): ");
    Serial.print(_controller.getValue());
    Serial.print("  Controller in initialize(): ");
    Serial.print(controller.getValue());

    Serial.print("  Controller Ptr in initialize(): ");
    Serial.print(controllerRef.getValue());

    Serial.println();
}

void Controller2::process(Controller &controller)
{
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("_Controller in process(): ");
    Serial.print(_controller.getValue());
    Serial.print("  Controller in process(): ");
    Serial.print(controller.getValue());

    Controller &controllerRef = *_controllerPtr;
    Serial.print("  Controller Ptr in process(): ");
    Serial.print(controllerRef.getValue());

    Serial.println();
}
```

Controller2.h:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Controller.h"

#ifndef Controller2_h
#define Controller2_h

class Controller2
{
public:
    Controller2();
    void initialize(Controller &controller, Controller* controllerPtr);
    void manage();
    void process(Controller &controller);

private:
    Controller _controller;
    Controller* _controllerPtr;
};

#endif
```

Controller Class:

```
#include "Controller.h"

Controller::Controller()
{
}

void Controller::initialize()
{
}

void Controller::setValue(int val)
{
    value = val;
}

int Controller::getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Controller.h:

```
#include "Arduino.h"

#ifndef Controller_h
#define Controller_h

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller();
    void initialize();
    void manage();
    void setValue(int val);
    int getValue();

private:
    int value = 0;
};

#endif
```

And the main class:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Controller.h>
#include <Controller2.h>

Controller controller;
Controller2 controller2;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Controller initial: ");
  Serial.print(controller.getValue());
  Serial.println();

  controller2.initialize(controller, &controller);
  controller2.process(controller);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

The output results in:

```
Controller initial: 0

_Controller in initialize(): 0  Controller in initialize(): 5  Controller Ptr in initialize(): 5

_Controller in process(): 0  Controller in process(): 5  Controller Ptr in process(): 5
```

Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: Generally, you need pointers like you need another hole in your head. If you have a choice, pass by reference. I’m not saying that pointers are always a bad choice, just most of the time. And you should never have to resort to using new[] and delete[] to allocate heap memory — use a vector instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"convert it to a reference every time I need to use it outside the scope."* - there is no need to "convert" pointers to references to use them. And you can have pointer member variables (or reference member variables if you only ever assign them in the constructor of a class)

Comment: Something strange is happening in the code you haven't shown us. Could you give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: ...My mistake, I got a couple of the variable names mixed up. But the edit was worthwhile.

Comment: @OP -- Here is some advice in general -- throw away everything you have learned from Java and C# when learning C++.   C++ is a different language, with different paradigms than Java or C#.  Today you're confused about references, and want to make the C++ code "act like" Java or C#, then tomorrow it will be something else where you're trying to write C++ to mimic Java or C#.  Writing C++ code by using other languages as a model is a quick road to disaster.  Either the program will have bugs, be inefficient, or just look plain weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: What Java and C# call a *reference*, C++ calls a *pointer*.  (The Java NPE is an exposure of that implementation detail.)  What C++ calls a *reference* does not have a counterpart in Java or C#.

Answer (score 3):

The truth is that C++ references behave in many ways like pointers, without the pointer-specific syntax.  For both pointers and references you have the pointer/reference-to-an-object and then you have the object itself, and the lifetime of the pointer/reference can differ from the lifetime of the object that it points-to/references, so in cases where the pointer/reference outlives the object, you have to be very careful not to dereference the pointer/reference after the object has been destroyed, or else you'll invoke  undefined behavior and your program won't behave well.

So for example this is valid:

```
class Controller2
{
public:
   Controller2(Controller & controllerRef) 
      : _controllerRef(controllerRef)
   {/*empty*/}

private:
   Controller & _controllerRef;
};
```

... and behaves much the same as the pointer-based implementation:

```
class Controller2
{
public:
   Controller2(ControllerPtr * controllerPtr) 
      : _controllerPtr(controllerPtr)
   {/*empty*/}

private:
   Controller * _controllerPtr;
};
```

... the main difference being that in the reference-based implementation, there is no (legal) way for the user to pass in a NULL reference to the Controller2 constructor, therefore your code doesn't have to worry about checking _controllerRef to see if it's NULL, since the language guarantees it won't be NULL (or to be more specific, it says that if the reference is NULL, then the program is already broken beyond repair, so you can assume it isn't NULL).

In both cases, passing a raw-pointer/reference to an external object is a bit risky, so unless you have some other way to guarantee that the pointed-to/referenced object will outlive any possible dereferencing of _controllerRef, you might be better off either making a private copy of the object, or if that isn't practical, using something like a shared_ptr or unique_ptr instead to guarantee that the referenced object won't be destroyed until after you've stopped holding any references to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to start thinking of things in terms of ownership of the memory. C++ doesn't have a garbage collector, so it's your job to manage who owns what memory.

Normally, the owner of the memory maintains the actual memory itself, or in the case of large (or virtual) data, maintains a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to it. `std::unique_ptr` is just like a raw pointer except that it enforces (a) the memory is cleaned up when you're done with it, and (b) there's only one unique pointer to the data at a given moment.

If you need to let someone *borrow* the data (i.e. let a function do something with it), then you pass a reference. `MyClass&` is a type that looks at someone else's `MyClass` instance and might modify it. `const MyClass&` is a type that looks at someone else's `MyClass` and doesn't modify it (for obvious reasons, you should default to the latter unless mutability is required).

If you need a value to have multiple owners, then first think about whether you really need it. Lots of things fit into the single-ownership model, and generally with some minor restructuring you can get by just fine with references and unique pointers. But if you really need multi-ownership, you can use [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to get that behavior (strong vs. weak references; you can read more about the difference at those links). But this should be the exception rather than the norm.

You should use raw pointers (i.e. `MyClass*`) almost *never*. In fact, as a C++ beginner, you should use raw pointers *literally* never. For collections, use `std::vector`, not a raw array that decays to a pointer (there are reasons to use the latter, but those are technical and only serve to confuse when just starting out). For individual data, use single- or multi- ownership as discussed above. If you write `MyClass*` somewhere, you should be able to replace it with a reference or a smart pointer (unique, shared, or weak). If you write `new` or `delete` somewhere, you should be able to replace it with a smart pointer constructor or simple value allocation (lots of Java devs coming to C++ find themselves writing `MyClass* x = new MyClass()` when `MyClass x{}` will do just fine).

My last major C++ project was a 13kloc programming language interpreter, and I used exactly one raw pointer in it (I remember specifically when I made this concession), to implement an obscure optimization trick in a critical path. There is a paragraph and a half of comments around that explaining why I had to do it and who actually owns the memory, since the type no longer communicates that information. Everything else was references and smart pointers. When you get the hang of it, you almost never need actual raw pointers.

Finally, a couple of pieces of advice.

1. Java and C# rely heavily on `null`. Try to avoid `nullptr` / `NULL` in C++. If you want a value that may or may not exist, [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is the idiomatic way to do it (if you don't have access to C++17, Boost has a header-only library to do the same). In particular, you should never make a value into a pointer for the sole purpose of allowing `nullptr`; that's what `std::optional` was designed specifically to do.
2. You may run into some really old code or tutorials online that use [`std::auto_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr). Do *not* use this type. `std::unique_ptr` does everything it does better. `std::auto_ptr` is a broken implementation and should never be used.

Comment: Hi. I just got interested in your project. Is it called `latitude`? I want to know if I was looking at the right repo.

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, that's the one. Feel free to open a GitHub issue or email me (address is on my GH account) if you have any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give the C++ perspective. To give you a starting point, as you come from a Java/C# perspective:

A variable that holds an object in Java (or C#) corresponds roughly to a variable that holds a [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in C++. There are differences, so don't expect that you should (or even can) simply "think Java" and use a `shared_ptr`. (You should "think C++" when coding in C++, just like you should "think Java" when coding in Java.) However, when comparing Java code and C++ code, thinking of Java objects as C++ shared pointers covers the 80% case. This should help you catch yourself when you try to apply semantics from another language (Java or C#) to C++ code.

Some additional reading:

- [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)
- [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

---

Even though you asked about "pass by" (implying function parameters), the real issue behind your symptom appears to be the `_controller` member. This is neither a reference nor a pointer; it is an object. Each `Controller2` object has a `Controller` object as a member. The number of `Controller` objects will be at least the number of `Controller2` objects. These are not shared. The line `_controller = controller;` does not make `_controller` refer to the same object as `controller`. No, it copies values to `_controller` from `controller`, the same way that assigning `int` variables copies a value.

One way to see this is to add a line to your code:

```cpp
    controller.setValue(5);   \\ existing line, affects parameter
    _controller.setValue(20); \\ new line, affects member
```

This gives your two `Controller` objects values that are distinct from each other, and distinct from the initial value. (The two `Controller` objects are the global variable named `controller` and the `_controller` member of the global variable named `controller2`.)

Some additional reading:

- [Should I prefer pointers or references in member data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data)