# Rationale behind C++ member variables declaration

Tags: c++, language-design

I am still pretty new to c++ and would like to understand the thought process behind creating member variables the way it is. For example, if I go through a header file, I see some of the member variables are declared as pointers while some others are declared as references.

```
// in foo.h

class Foo {
  private:
    A* const a;
    B& b;
    std::unique_ptr<C> c;
};
```

What is the difference between declaring (is this even the correct terminology?) `a`,`b` & `c` the way it is? I understand that `a` is `const pointer`, i.e., it points to some memory holding an object of type `A` & `b` is a reference. `c` is a `unique_ptr` holding an object of type `C`. But I don't understand why you would want to declare something this way. I come from a Java/Python background so please bear with my confusion.

Comment: `B& b;` makes the shown code uncompilable.

Comment: Is the fact that these are members relevant? Do you understand [the difference between pointers and references as (non-member) variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable)?

Comment: @JaMiT I guess the fact that these are members are not really relevant. Thanks for the link. So if I understand correctly, you don't have to initialize the references, but once you initialize them in the constructor or at object creation time, then you can't change it. 

That would mean the rationale behind declaring them this way is to not change b after object initializtion. Am I correct?

Comment: @273K this is a header file and object is not initialized yet. Would it still make it uncompilable?

Comment: As long as A, B, C are declared, and `#include <memory>` is done, and `Foo` is never instantiated anywhere, it will compile.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate (in part) of: [Should I prefer pointers or references as data members?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/892133/5740428)

Comment: `object is not initialized yet` What do you want to do there if the class in the header as is is completely defined?

Comment: Don't learn C++ by trying to compare it with Java or Python.  C++ is a very large and complex language, with lots of history and some unpleasant aspects because it tries to be backwards compatible.  Learn C++ from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: Java was designed to remove pointers as much as possible since pointers in C and C++ are known to be the root of a lot of defects.  A pointer can point to anywhere and a dereferenced invalid pointer is undefined behavior (often difficult to track down).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B& b;
```

The above is a reference to a B object.  As a reference, it can never be NULL, and it cannot be re-targeted to refer to a different object than the one it was originally initialized to refer to.  You can also access it via the same syntax that you would use for a "normal" member-variable (e.g. as if it were `B b;`).  Since it is unchangeable, its presence means that you must set it as via an initializer in each of your constructors, otherwise you will get a compile-time error.

```
A* const a;
```

The above is a pointer to a read-only A object... or it could be set to NULL, in which case it isn't pointing to anything valid at all.  Since its value can be changed at run-time, it does not need to be initialized by your object's constructors (although it is considered good practice to at least initialize it to NULL, so that if any of your code tries to access it before it is set, you'll be more likely to get an obvious/reproducible crash)

```
std::unique_ptr<C> c;
```

This is similar to `C * c;` except better (assuming your object is intended to "own" the C object), because it explicitly indicates the ownership relation and will automatically delete the pointed-to C object when the `unique_ptr` is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes a lot of sense. A few follow-up question. When would I want to use `B b` over `B& b`? Is `B b` changable after initialization, or maybe it doesn't even have to be initialized through the constructors.

When you mean "own", does that mean if object `foo` goes out of scope, `c` will get destroyed, but that is not true for `a`?

Comment: You'd use `B b` when the `b` object is always to be stored within the `Foo` object; `B & b` would only be necessary if you want `b` to reference a `B` object that is located somewhere else.  `B b` is modifiable after initialization, although the change I was referring to for `B & b` was that the reference can't be retargetted to refer to a different object.  Your description of what "own" means is what I intended.

Answer (score 2):

> would like to understand the thought process behind creating member variables the way it is

Note that this has nothing to do with member variables - the same constraints apply to pointers/references/smart pointers in *any* scope. I.e. those may well be global variables, automatic local variables in a function, static globals or static locals, etc.

A lot of it has to do with making the code understandable to the human beings. The convention is, usually:

- `a` is a non-owning pointer,
- `b` is an immutable reference (non-owning) to a single object that must exist as long as the reference exists,
- `c` is an owning pointer that manages the lifetime of the pointed-to object.

The choice between a non-owning pointer and a reference boils down to how the pointer/reference is used. If the APIs/libraries used already pass certain objects via object pointer and not by reference, then that's what you'd go with. If you ever need to change what object is referred to, a pointer must be used.

The reference makes it very clear that there is a single object (and not, let's say an array of them, or a `nullptr`), and it is immutable. That means that once the reference is bound to an object, it will remain bound to that object for as long as the reference exists.

In C++ null references are undefined behavior, so you should never expect a reference to be null. In fact, any tests like `Obj& ref; ... if (&ref != nullptr) { do_something(); }` will reduce to `if (true) { do_something(); }`.

A reference makes a clear statement (to a human) that the class `Foo` requires the object at `b` to exist throughout `Foo`'s lifetime. Since the reference is immutable, the only chance to set it up is in the constructor. After construction, whatever object it refers to will remain until `Foo` instance gets destroyed.

It is undefined behavior to end the life of an object with references to it. "Undefined behavior" is a colloquial term for "if you do this, the compiler is allowed to do whatever with your code unless otherwise specified in compiler documentation". A behavior that's undefined in the C++ standard may well still be implementation-defined, but if you depend on that, you're making your code non-portable and dependent on a particular compiler implementation. It's sometimes unavoidable, but generally not a good thing.

Comment: Side note: Because a reference cannot be made to refer to another object after initialization, reference members make assignment operators tricky-to-impossible to write. You may find yourself forced into using pointers instead.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, it definitely involves some creative approaches. About the only standard-C++ approach would be to have some class/struct that encapsulates the references, and stick that  inside a `std::optional` or otherwise control the lifetime during assignment. E.g. `A&operator=(const A&o) { this->refs.~ARefs(); new (&this->refs) ARefs(o.ARefs); return *this; }`, where `ARefs` encaspulates the references that `A` needs.

Comment: "It is undefined behavior to end the life of an object with references to it." I'm not sure this is true. Rather, you cannot use a reference once the object it refers to has it's lifetime ended. Just like it's perfectly ok to end the life of some object while the pointer to it remains.